# CouchDb _replicate method returns Missing replicator database

Tags: couchdb

I have 2 users `u_801` and `u_807`:

[image]

I want to replicate SIMULATION document ID from u801 to u807 with POST `{couchURL}/_replicate` method:

```
{
    "source": "u_801", 
    "target ": "u_807",
    "doc_ids": ["SIMULATION"]
}
```

However, I get:

```
{"error":"error","reason":"Missing replicator database"}
```

If I replicate via UI `{couchURL}/_utils/#replication`, it replicates well but uses `_replicator` method.

Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the JSON doc that you post to _replicate endpoint.

```
{
    "source": "u_801", 
    "target ": "u_807",
    "doc_ids": ["SIMULATION"]
}
```

Look at "target " that has an space at the end, so the replicator does not find the specified target database.

Comment: Damn, missed that :D